# PHP truncates parameter name after squared brackets?

Tags: php, url, square-bracket

If the parameter name of an URL contains squared brackets (no matter if they are url-encoded or not), any following character is ignored by PHP and is not made available to the script (e.g. via $_GET).

Example request:

```
...showget.php?xxx%5B1%5Dyyy=42
```

$_GET:

```
Array
(
    [xxx] => Array
        (
            [1] => 42
        )
)
```

As you can see, "yyy" didn't made it. ^^

(tested in PHP 5.3.28 & 5.5.10)

1. Does somebody know if such URLs are even syntactically valid?
2. Is this behaviour intended and documented (could not find anything) or should it rather be considered as a bug within PHP?
3. If intended: Can i change the respective behaviour by changing a special setting or so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is intended behaviour. As you saw in your example, PHP builds arrays from GET parameters if it can, that is, if it finds square brackets in the variable name. There's a [FAQ entry](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays) showing how that can sometimes be useful.

In your case, PHP sees `xxx[1]yyy=42` as `xxx[1]=42` which becomes an array.

As far as I know, PHP's query string parsing can not be changed, but you could use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` and parse that yourself.

Comment: Understood, thx. But if we put PHP aside for a moment: Is such an URL syntactically correct, in terms of the official specification?

Comment: As far as I know, HTTP doesn't have any restrictions w.r.t. the syntax of query strings.

Answer (score 2):

`[]` in query key names is a hint to PHP that you want an array, e.g.

```
example.com?foo[]=bar&foo[]=baz
```

produces

```
$_GET = array(
   'foo' => array('bar', 'baz')
);
```

This notation also lets you specify keys in the url:

```
example.com?foo[bar]=baz

$_GET = array(
   'foo' => array('bar' => 'baz')
);
```

But once you get into this array notation, you're not permitted to have anything in the keyname AFTER the `[]` portion:

```
example.com?foo[bar]baz=qux

$_GET = array(
   'foo' => array('bar' => 'qux')
);
```

Basically it's related to PHP syntax, where somethign like

```
$foo['bar']baz
```

would be a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this myself earlier too, and wrote a function to handle it from POST data, but it shouldn't take much to get it to use GET data instead. Such a large amount of code simply to account for the fact that PHP doesn't account for nested square brackets ;-)

```
/**
 * Gets the _POST data with correct handling of nested brackets:
 * "path[to][data[nested]]=value"
 * "path"
 *    -> "to"
 *       -> "data[nested]" = value
 * @return array
 */
function get_real_post() {

    function set_nested_value(&$arr, &$keys, &$value) {
        $key = array_shift($keys);
        if (count($keys)) {
            // Got deeper to go
            if (!array_key_exists($key, $arr)) {
                // Make sure we can get deeper if we've not hit this key before
                $arr[$key] = array();
            } elseif (!is_array($arr[$key])) {
                // This should never be relevant for well formed input data
                throw new Exception("Setting a value and an array with the same key: $key");
            }
            set_nested_value($arr[$key], $keys, $value);
        } elseif (empty($key)) {
            // Setting an Array
            $arr[] = $value;
        } else {
            // Setting an Object
            $arr[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    $input = array();
    $parts = array();
    $pairs = explode("&", file_get_contents("php://input"));
    foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
        $key_value = explode("=", $pair, 2);
        preg_match_all("/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)(?:\[([^\[\]]*(?:(?R)[^\[\]]*)*)\])?/", urldecode($key_value[0]), $parts);
        $keys = array($parts[1][0]);
        if (!empty($parts[2][0])) {
            array_pop($parts[2]); // Remove the blank one on the end
            $keys = array_merge($keys, $parts[2]);
        }
        $value = urldecode($key_value[1]);
        if ($value == "true") {
            $value = true;
        } else if ($value == "false") {
            $value = false;
        } else if (is_numeric($value)) {
            if (strpos($value, ".") !== false) {
                $num = floatval($value);
            } else {
                $num = intval($value);
            }
            if (strval($num) === $value) {
                $value = $num;
            }
        }
        set_nested_value($input, $keys, $value);
    }
    return $input;
}
```